Merge cell in Excel with criteria
I'm working with an Excel file. I'm hoping someone out there can show me a macro that might help me because I'm in a time crunch and I don't know how to solve this manually.
The sheet contains online shop transaction data. I need to find a way to combine rows based on some criteria. For example, IF the transaction numbers are the same, THEN the values ​​are merge and not added up.
 ----->>>>> 
in Real case


Using Dict object to get the merged area.
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey, c As Range, arrData
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rngData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    ' sort table
    rngData.Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Header:=xlNo
    ' load data into an array
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1)
        ' get merged range with Dict object
        If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            Set objDic(sKey) = Union(objDic(sKey), Cells(i, 2))
        Else
            Set objDic(sKey) = Cells(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    ' merge range on Col B
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each sKey In objDic.Keys
        Set c = objDic(sKey)
        If c.Cells.Count > 1 Then
            c.Merge
        End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub


I think this answer is appropriate, but in a real problem like this picture Real case image , which code should I change?

Done, I changed sKey = arrData(i, 1) to sKey = arrData(i, 3) and Set objDic(sKey) = Union(objDic(sKey), Cells(i, 2)) to Set objDic(sKey) = Union (objDic(sKey), Cells(i, 8))

If you have Excel 2024/365 you can use the UNIQUE functions:
=UNIQUE(A1:B15)



This VBA code return in the source cells the result as on the sample screenshot.
Place it in the sheet's code module.
Sub MERGE_COL()

For i = 1 To Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
  If Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 1) = Range("A" & i).Offset(1, 1) And _
  Range("A" & i) = Range("A" & i + 1) Then
    Range("B" & i) = ""
  End If
Next i

End Sub



It seems to me the best way is to use "Remove Duplicates":

The result is demonstrated in D:E.
If you prefer to get the result as requested:
Option Explicit

Sub Merge()
  Dim i As Long, j As Long
  [A1].CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=[A:A], Key2:=[B:B], Header:=xlYes
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  i = 3: j = 2
  While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))
    If Cells(i, 1) <> Cells(j, 1) Or Cells(i, 2) <> Cells(j, 2) Then
      Cells(j, 2).Resize(i - j, 1).Merge
      Cells(j, 2).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
      j = i
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Wend
  Cells(j, 2).Resize(i - j, 1).Merge
  Cells(j, 2).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub


Good one, would love to see a parameterized version :)

Please consider that cell merging can be good for representation but makes further data analysis difficult.

Thank you very much for the answer and solution.
I followed the answer and changed some parameters and it was as expected for the results.


Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
Dim i As Long, sKey, c As Range, arrData
Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set rngData = Range("C1").CurrentRegion
' load data into an array
arrData = rngData.Value
For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
    sKey = arrData(i, 3)
    ' get merged range with Dict object
    If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
        Set objDic(sKey) = Union(objDic(sKey), Cells(i, 8))
    Else
        Set objDic(sKey) = Cells(i, 8)
    End If
Next i
' merge range on Col B
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each sKey In objDic.Keys
    Set c = objDic(sKey)
    If c.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        c.Merge
    End If
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub



